# extension translation in typo3

Tags: translation, extbase

I'm working on translating a page in Frontend ( Extbase view ) from English to German . The view outputs a list of some countries ( stored in the database in English ) and some labels , for example " Please choose your country " .

Now I want to translate the data (countries that are grabbed from the database )  as well as the labels depending on the value of L that is set = 1 for German language .

I looked on the internet , but most tutorials are in German and they don't get to the point ,the majority cover how you should duplicate "locallang.xlf" to "de.locallang.xlf" and that's it , they don't clarify the next step to do to make it work . So I would really appreciate it if you could help me or guide me to a nice tutorial that covers all the steps from a to z .

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial in my opinion:
https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/language-files.html

It's quite easy to set up the language files to work with different ISO codes.